# Curl working on command line but not inside Expect script

Tags: curl, expect

I am using this curl command outside and it works fine, 
But when I try to use the same inside Expect script, it throws some weird output,

Below is my code:

```
spawn curl -u $myuserid $url > $hname
expect "'$myuserid':" {send $mypwd\r}
expect ">"
```

Output is like,
    �QrM­���L�h�

I am new to scripting, please advise

Answer (score 0):

`spawn` does not launch a shell, and `curl` doesn't understand `>`. Try this:

```
spawn sh -c "curl -u $myuserid $url > $hname"
```

Answer (score 0):

I am trying to make this work on an AIX system.
The one-line command does not work, but splitting it up and making a delay to let the shell start up before sending the curl-part, works

```
spawn qsh
sleep 5
send "curl -k --proxytunnel -x http://proxy_details sftp://host_details/ -o folderList.txt\n"
```